# How to get Object from database using it's Key?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get an Object from database using it's key, but it is not working.

Here is my database :

[DATABASE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZrq4.png)

DATABASE:

```html
...
 - toc-list
           |___ id1 (generated by firebase)
                  |___ field1
                  |___ field2

           |___ id2 (generated by firebase)
                  |___ field1
                  |___ field2

           |___ id3 (generated by firebase)
                  |___ field1
                  |___ field2
```

I am trying to get an Object from toc-list by using the id1 "-Ld6AAdHn6JBYcrh29Xz"

I have tried to get it like this, but it is not working :

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import firebase from 'firebase';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-confrontation-1',
  templateUrl: 'confrontation-1.html',
})
export class Confrontation_1Page {

  toc_id : string;
  public toc: Array<any> = [];
  public tocRef: firebase.database.Reference = firebase.database().ref('/toc-list');

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public afDB: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.toc_id = navParams.get('tocId');
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad Confrontation_1Page');

    // I want to show the details of the element that has the id : toc_id
    console.log(this.afDB.object('/toc-list/' + this.toc_id));

  }


}
```

Comment: Angular Fire uses `Observables`. Try `this.afDB.object('/toc-list/' + this.toc_id).valueChanges()` and check out this: https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/objects.md#create-an-object-binding.

Comment: @DaniR it returned an Observable object, but it is not the object that I am looking for, it has returned this :

Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
operator: MapOperator {project: ƒ, thisArg: undefined}
source: Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: RefCountOperator}
_isScalar: false
__proto__: Object

Comment: Can you provide more code to see what you are doing with the result?

Comment: @DaniR yes I edited the post

Comment: @DaniR I have also updated the picture of the database, I want to display the fields : degre, detail, heure... ect

Comment: Try in your constructor `this.afDB.object('/toc-list/' + this.toc_id).valueChanges().subscribe(res => console.log(res))`. Observables are async and you have to wait for a result.

Comment: @DaniR it worked, thank you

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to unsubscribe after the view was destroyed. I will create an answer and would be glad about an upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observable are async and you have to subscribe on it. Try:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import firebase from 'firebase';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-confrontation-1',
  templateUrl: 'confrontation-1.html',
})
export class Confrontation_1Page {

  toc_id : string;
  public toc: Array<any> = [];
  public tocRef: firebase.database.Reference = firebase.database().ref('/toc-list');

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public afDB: AngularFireDatabase) {
    this.toc_id = navParams.get('tocId');
    this.afDB.object('/toc-list/' + this.toc_id).valueChanges().subscribe(res => console.log(res))
  }

  ionViewDidLeave() {
    this.afDB.object('/toc-list/' + this.toc_id).valueChanges().unsubscribe();
  }


}
```